# Create a file with several arrays in java

Tags: arrays, file, stream, size, createfile

Given a byte array I can make a file from it with the code

```
Files.write(String path, byte[] byteArray)
```

The problem is, since I have to work with extremely large array sizes, and I can't make an array with a long size

```
long n = 100000000;
byte byteArray = new byte[n]; //ERROR! Required int, found long
```

what I do is I have several byte arrays. For example, since I can't have a 4gb array, I make 20 byte arrays of 200mb. These 20 arrays represent the information of a file. Now, how can I create a file from this byte arrays? The only way I know is using Files.write, but that only works with 1 array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
Files.write(path, bytes, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

On the calls after the first one.

A better method (that doesn't require re-opening the file 20 times) would be using a [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) like:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
for(int i = 0; i < byteArrays.length; ++i)
{
    fos.write(byteArrays[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Using StandardOpenOption.APPEND I can write all the byte arrays one after the other. Works perfectly.